# What effect does a capacitor have in controlling a small DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, control

I have a small DC motor which was salvaged (shaft is 1.5", total height of case [excluding shaft] is 1.132" and it's .82" inches wide). It has no markings that I can discern, other than a handwritten "+" and "-" on the terminals. It also has a 100uF eiectrolytic can cap soldered to the + and - motor terminals. I have a B100K pot and am using a 9V battery to power the motor. When I adjust the pot, the motor goes to full power with only the center terminal of the pot connected to the + of the motor. It sounded simple to me.

I've seen a related question, except in that case the motor would not turn on at all. Is there a way to do attenuate the motor's speed with the parts listed, or do I need to use an Arduino?

Comment: The pots resistance is to high for the motor. The capacitor will smooth the DC and help reduce the conducted emissions. With that cap you cannot reverse the motor, that will reverse polarity to the capacitor causing it to fail, some times spectacularly.

Comment: Ah- eureka! I wish I remembered what else I had done, but I had tried to jumper some connections at the pot; at one point I could get the motor to go in either direction, but now it only spins one way, full speed. The cap looks okay, but I'll remove it and see what happens. What size pot would you recommend- I'm very much the beginner!

Comment: You probably do not need the cap. Just reverse the power and the motor should reverse. I am assuming it is a brush type motor, not a brushless one.

Comment: Post a photo of the motor. Do you have a multimeter? If so, measure resistance between the motor terminals, and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A motor is not going to work very well with any value potentiometer directly connected. A small motor can be controlled to some extent with a rheostat connection, but the value needs to be on the order of motor rated voltage divided by rated current. The rheostat power needs to be on the order of motor rated power. A 9V battery of the type with snap connectors on top is likely to have too little current capacity for most motors.

I recommend that you try AA or AAA cells. Try 1, 2, 3 or more in series. That will give you several speeds.

There is not likely any good reason to connect a capacitor.

If the motor turns with a 9V battery, you may need about 1K variable resistance in series to control the speed with no load. Any load will further decrease the speed or stall the motor.

Comment: It's got a good amount of unloaded speed, but I'm guessing not much torque. And, so far I've not been able to read any markings in the motor- it's a can approximately an inch high and .75'" across, with a plastic base and a slightly smaller diameter neat the shaft, approximately1/16" or less smaller that the rest of the motor.

Comment: Do you know what it was used for?

Comment: I don't remember-  it was from a box of parts. Under a good light, I was able to read "Super Jack", which is a Chinese manufacturer, and R-2 which was molded into the plastic, so I'm sure it's pretty old.

Comment: I added to my answer. You should add the motor dimensions to the question.

Comment: Dimensions added to the question per request.

Comment: Did you make a mistake about shaft dimension?

Comment: I added series resistance guess.

Comment: Shaft dimension is the total length in inches, measured with a caliper.